# Variable Seems to Force Integer Answers in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a number that is calculated in Perl and once I get it back from a subroutine and do some multiplication, I use it to find another number and the second number is always a rounded down integer.

Here's my code:

```
$gap = timediff($date, $next);
$gap = ($gap / 60) / 24;
$total = $total + $amt;
$time = $gap/365;
print "Gap: $gap, time: $time\n";
```

Whenever I run this, the answer for $time is always 0.  (I'm working with time periods and, for now, it's always less than a year.)  So I added another print statement:

```
print "Compute: ".($gap/365).", Calc test: ".($gap * .72)."\n";
```

I get 0 for both answers.

On the second calculation (after "Calc Test: "), I've used addition, division, subtraction, and multiplication, as well as replacing the .72 with different numbers.  If I divide, the answer is always a rounded down integer.

I'm also including the code for timediff() and unhtime(), which it calls.  timediff() does what you'd expect, it calculates the elapsed time between two times.  The unhtime() takes times and converts it from a format I use sometimes (yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss) and converts it back to ticks.  In this case, I'm passing it dates that have no hhmmss part (which Perl handles nicely by returning nothing for the part of the string that doesn't exist).  I get accurate results with this, but I've never had to deal with decimals before and at some point in this process, something is affecting a number and not only forcing it to be an integer, but forcing any future calculations made with it to return integers.

```
sub timediff {
my ($now, $then, $diff);
($now, $then) = @_;
$now = unhtime($now);
$then = unhtime($then);
$diff = int(($then - $now) / 60);
return $diff;
}

sub unhtime {
my $start = shift(@_);
if (!$start) {$start = humantime();}
$start =~ s/-//g;
my $year = substr($start, 0, 4);
my $month = substr($start, 4, 2);
my $day = substr($start, 6, 2);
my $hour = substr($start, 8, 2);
my $min = substr($start, 10, 2);
my $sec = substr($start, 12, 2);
$year = $year - 1900;
$month--;
my $now = timelocal($sec, $min, $hour, $day, $month, $year);
return $now;
```

}

(The timelocal is from Time::Local.)

Why are any operations where I use $gap being forced to rounded down integer answers?

Comment: Re "Why are any operations where I use $gap being forced to rounded down integer answers?" Not bloody likely. Please give a minimal, runnable demonstration of the problem.

Comment: @ikegami Not unlikely: maybe there's a `use integer` around?

Comment: @ikegami: I figure if there's something in Perl that forces an integer result in a string and, from then on, forces integers, then whatever code I post would actually be irrelevant.

Comment: @SlavenRezic: I don't use one in my modules.  If one is used in another module I call, would that have an effect on the result that is returned to my code?  And, if so, what can I do to counter that effect?

Comment: @Tango: `use integer` is a pragma, so it's lexically scoped. Which means: if you don't see it, then it has no effect on your code.

Comment: @Tango Have you ever checked that the very first `$gap` isn't already zero?

Comment: `$gap` could be an object that overloads operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in `timediff` is forcing this integer rounding:

```
...
$diff = int(($then - $now) / 60);
```

From `perldoc -f int`:

> Returns the integer portion of EXPR.  If EXPR is omitted, uses
>   $_.  You should not use this function for rounding: one because
>   it truncates towards 0, and two because machine representations
>   of floating-point numbers can sometimes produce
>   counterintuitive results.

Comment: So once I use int(), that forces that number, from then on, to yield integer results?  Is there any way to change that?  Once I use int(), how can I force that variable to be treated like a floating point later?

Comment: @Tango You can't. Whatever extra information was in the expression `($then - $now) / 60` is forever lost once you assign the integer part to `$diff`. You can return both (integer part and floating point number) as an array: `$diff= ($then-$now)/60; return ($diff,int $diff)`

Comment: I may edit that routine, then.  Rather than using int(), I'll use a regex to remove the decimal point and anything after that.

Comment: Just tried another hack.  After getting the result, I added this: $gap = "$gap.00"; and after that, it was treated as a floating point.

Comment: Re: "So once I use int(), that forces that number, from then on, to yield integer results", not at all. `perl -E'say int(4)*0.1'` prints 0.4

Comment: @ikegami: But that's not what I'm experiencing.  Once int() has been used on the value, from then on, any results I get are integer results.

Comment: @Tango That's because you stored in `$diff` the output of `int` which indeed contains no floating point information. If you were to use `$then` and `$now` in other expressions, you would still be able to access their fractional parts.

Comment: @JosephR.: So it's storing it that makes it used as an int in the future?  And since ikegami didn't store anything in his example, that's why it worked?

Comment: @Tango What I meant is that `int` doesn't touch the values in `$then` and `$now` it only produces the integer part of its input. Only this integer part is what makes it into `$diff` so whenever you use `$diff` you'll get an integer because it knows nothing about `$then` and `$now`: only the output of `int`. The operation of storing (more formally _assignment_) does nothing special here beyond providing scalar context to the right hand side.